# AWS Lambda. docClient.query call will not update an existing outside variable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am unsuccessfully trying to get a dynamoDB query function to update an existing outer/global variable inside a node.js lambda function.

```
var responseBody;
docClient.query(BookmarkParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    context.fail(err);
  }else{
    responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
  }
});
```

responseBody is always undefined or if I give it a value at the top level it stays that way and is never updated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your whole code?

Comment: where is responseBody undefined. Plz share that piece of code.

Comment: var responseBody;
docClient.query(BookmarkParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    context.fail(err);
  }else{
    responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
  }
});
console.log(responseBody); //This always comes back undefined